# How to set localslots_cpp when distcc is used with ccache?

Tags: ccache, distcc

From distcc's [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/distcc#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two,local%20resource%20usage.) I understand that localslots_cpp can limit the concurrency of preprocessing. But the setting of localslots_cpp doesn't work when called via ccache.